# Color picking with glReadPixels works with offset on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, opengl-es, glreadpixels

- Qt 6.6.1
- Qt 6.7.0 beta
- Windows 10

I wrote a simple example that shows a problem. This example draws a red triangle on the background with (0.2, 0.2, 0.2) color. I implemented the `mousePressEvent` method. When you click on the canvas the example will print a color to the console. I tested this example on Windows 10 and WebAssembly - it works as expected. For example how it works on WebAssembly:

[image]

But on Android (both: real device connected with USB-cable and Android Emulator) it works with offset. So I draw a triangle in the center but it looks like I draw it in the top right corner. When I touch on the triangle it prints (0.2, 0.2, 0.2) to the console but when I touch to the top right corner it prints (1, 0, 0) like the triangle in the top right corner. It looks like the beginning of coordinate system for glReadPixels is in the center of the window:

[image]

```cpp
    void paintGL() override
    {
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        m_program.bind();
        m_vertPosBuffer.bind();
        m_program.setAttributeBuffer(m_aPositionLocation, GL_FLOAT, 0, 2);
        m_program.enableAttributeArray(m_aPositionLocation);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        // qDebug() << glGetError() << "\n";

        if (m_mouseClicked)
        {
            // Read the pixel
            GLubyte pixel[4];
            glReadPixels(m_mouseX, m_mouseY, 1, 1,
                         GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
            // qDebug() << glGetError() << "\n";
            qDebug() << pixel[0] / 255.f << pixel[1] / 255.f << pixel[2] / 255.f << "\n";
            qDebug() << m_mouseX << m_mouseY << "\n";
            m_mouseClicked = false;
        }
    }

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        m_mouseX = event->pos().x();
        m_mouseY = height() - event->pos().y() - 1;
        m_mouseClicked = true;
        update();
    }
```

I don't know it is bug of Qt or something else. I think glReadPixels is a very popular method to pick objects using the "Color ID" method and a lot of people had the same problem. Maybe someone know how to avoid this problem? I created a bug report where you can download a zip and try my example: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-120648

Cross-refs:

- https://forum.qt.io/topic/153380/qt-6-6-1-android-glreadpixels-reads-the-pixel-color-from-wrong-position
- https://community.khronos.org/t/qt-6-6-1-android-glreadpixels-reads-the-pixel-color-from-wrong-position/110404

Comment: Why are you adding half a screen to the coordinates of readpixel?

Comment: It is for avoiding of offset. Like a temporary solution. I added a gif-animation for Android Emulator to the topic. See the output to the console on the gif-animation. It allows to "move" a triangle to the center of the screen. This works close to the expected behavior. It looks like the beginning of coordinate system for glReadPixels is in the center of the window.

Comment: In my example from the zip on the bug report I call `glReadPixels` like this: `glReadPixels(m_mouseX, m_mouseY, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);` But for an experiment I tried to make an offset. I added this info to the topic. Now you can see a code in the topic. It looks more clear for understanding why I tried to add half a screen to the coordinates of `glReadPixels`.

Comment: I have deleted an info about my experiment with adding half a screen to the coordinates of `glReadPixels`. It was deleted from the bug report too: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-120648 I have added an info about it in the next topic to this message: https://forum.qt.io/post/787212

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution in comments here: [OpenGL support broken with high-dpi (Retina) on OS X](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31000). It is for macOS but it is true for Android too. The comment of Laszlo Agocs helped me:

> You need to adjust the GL positions based on the devicePixelRatio(). If the window is size N,M and devicePixelRatio() is 2 then the GL framebuffer, viewport will all have a size of 2*N,2*M. Try multiplying mouseX and mouseY with devicePixelRatio().

Solution:

```cpp
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        m_mouseX = event->pos().x() * devicePixelRatio();
        m_mouseY = (height() - event->pos().y() - 1) * devicePixelRatio();
        m_mouseClicked = true;
        update();
    }
```

[image]

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <QtGui/QMouseEvent>
#include <QtGui/QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QtOpenGL/QOpenGLBuffer>
#include <QtOpenGL/QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QtOpenGL/QOpenGLWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

class OpenGLWindow : public QOpenGLWindow, private QOpenGLFunctions
{
    int m_mouseX;
    int m_mouseY;
    bool m_mouseClicked = false;
    QOpenGLBuffer m_vertPosBuffer;
    QOpenGLShaderProgram m_program;

    void initializeGL() override
    {
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.f);
        qDebug() << "Device pixel ratio:" << devicePixelRatio();

        QString vertexShaderSource =
            "attribute vec2 aPosition;\n"
            "void main()\n"
            "{\n"
            "    gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
            "}\n";

        QString fragmentShaderSource =
            "#ifdef GL_ES\n"
            "precision mediump float;\n"
            "#endif\n"
            "void main()\n"
            "{\n"
            "    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
            "}\n";

        m_program.create();
        m_program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::ShaderTypeBit::Vertex,
                                          vertexShaderSource);
        m_program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::ShaderTypeBit::Fragment,
                                          fragmentShaderSource);
        m_program.link();
        m_program.bind();

        float vertPositions[] = {
            -0.5f, -0.5f,
            0.5f, -0.5f,
            0.f, 0.5f
        };
        m_vertPosBuffer.create();
        m_vertPosBuffer.bind();
        m_vertPosBuffer.allocate(vertPositions, sizeof(vertPositions));

        m_program.setAttributeBuffer("aPosition", GL_FLOAT, 0, 2);
        m_program.enableAttributeArray("aPosition");
    }

    void paintGL() override
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        if (m_mouseClicked)
        {
            // Read the pixel
            GLubyte pixel[4];
            glReadPixels(m_mouseX, m_mouseY, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
            // qDebug() << glGetError() << "\n";
            qDebug() << pixel[0] / 255.f << pixel[1] / 255.f << pixel[2] / 255.f;
            m_mouseClicked = false;
        }
    }

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        m_mouseX = event->pos().x() * devicePixelRatio();
        m_mouseY = (height() - event->pos().y() - 1) * devicePixelRatio();
        m_mouseClicked = true;
        update();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    OpenGLWindow w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

pick-color-of-simple-triangle-qopenglwindow-qt6-cpp.pro

```
QT += core gui opengl widgets

win32: LIBS += -lopengl32

CONFIG += c++17

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

TARGET = app
```